# TSQL- Error in calling dynamic query with function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query I can run that works -

```
SELECT connected_clients, (ServerName + CacheType) AS metric, CreateDate AS time
FROM dbo.DiagnosticLog dl 
WHERE ServerName IN ('001        ', '002        ', '003        ')
  AND CacheType IN ('p.1   ', 'q.1   ', 'm.1     ', 'a-p.1   ', 'a-q.1   ', 'sentinel  ')
```

`connected_clients` is the column name so I need to make a dynamic query and I also need to call a function that will split words by comma like in ServerName and CacheType. This is my stored procedure that contains the dynamic query:

```
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME,
    @Message VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ServerName CHAR(150),
    @CacheType CHAR(150)
)   
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 
    ('SELECT '+ @Message +', (ServerName + CacheType )as metric, CreateDate  as time
    FROM DiagnosticLog 
    WHERE ServerName in ('+(SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@ServerName,','))+') AND 
        CacheType in ('+(SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@CacheType,','))+')   ')
    EXECUTE (@sql)
END
GO
```

This is how I'm calling the stored procedure

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME,
    @Message CHAR(20)

SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(HH,-24, GETDATE()) 
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()

EXECUTE storedProcedureName @StartDate, @EndDate ,  'connected_clients', '001        ,002        ,003        ' , 'p.1   ,q.1   ,m.1     ,a-p.1   ,a-q.1   ,sentinel  '
```

The error I get is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

**Edit**: I changed the `sql` string to

```
@sql = 
    'SELECT '+ @Message +', (ServerName + CacheType )as metric, CreateDate  as time
    FROM DiagnosticLog dl 
    WHERE ServerName in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(' +@ServerName + ','','')) AND 
        CacheType in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(' +@CacheType+ ','',''))   '
execute (@sql)
```

and I get an error of

> Incorrect syntax near '.1'

Comment: Post the error you are receiving.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include the error. :)

Comment: just added the error

Comment: @user9864738 Which part of the error message don't you understand???  I think the error message is very clear.  Run your subquery and see if it returns more than one row.  If it is, then there you go, you find the error.

Comment: Regarding the second error: `... CacheType in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(p.1   ,q.1   ,m.1     ,a-p.1   ,a-q.1   ,sentinel)) ...` doesn't make sense. `p` might be a column name, but the `.1` after it is where the parser gives up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting multiple values back from the query in `... ServerName in ('+(SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@ServerName,','))+') ...`,  but SQL Server won't magically concatenate the values back into a comma-delimited string for you.

Since `in` deals with comma-delimited lists, you could use `... ServerName in (' + @ServerName + ') ...` if the string elements are quoted. (Note that you changed from using `'001        ','002        ','003        '` in you working query, with each element quoted, to `'001        ,002        ,003        '` as a parameter value with the entire string quoted.)

Alternatively, let `in` use the subquery: `... ServerName in ( select * from dbo.SplitString( ''' + @ServerName + ''',',') ) ...`.

Note that both of these provide ample opportunity for [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Using a parameterized query with [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to pass the variable values would remove the possibility of SQL injection.

All of the above applies to the `CacheType` `in` expression as well.

Comment: Thank you, I had to add single quote marks around @serverName in the IN expression. Isn't what I'm doing using parameterized query with execute? I defined a sproc with properties

Comment: You are passing parameters to the stored procedure, but `execute` allows you to pass parameters as shown in the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `IN` keyword on this line:

```
CacheType ('+(SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@CacheType,','))+')   ')
```

You also should not put your sql string in parenthesis when you are declaring it.

Comment: forgot to add the in, but still received the same error

Comment: @user9864738 when you print `@sql` before executing it, what does it contain?